# Loading groups from LDAP using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I need to give access to users belonging to a group (ABCD) in LDAP. I am able to authenticate successfully with Spring LDAP security, but for some reason the group membership is not loaded. I get "403 access Denied" error when I try to login. I verified that the groups for the user are not populated into Authorities.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

Is there a way I can load groups of a user into authorities? Here is my spring security configuration.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**"
        access="true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**"
        access="true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**"
        access="true" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="hasRole('ABCD')" />

</security:http>

<security:ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="${ldap.url}" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        server-ref="ldapServer" user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people,o=xxxx.com"
        group-search-base="ou=groups,o=xxxx.com" />

</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
<security:ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="${ldap.url}/o=xxxx.com" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            group-search-filter="member={0}"
            group-search-base="ou=groups"
            user-search-base="ou=people"
            user-search-filter="uid={0}"
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The main your issue is around the `group-search-filter`, which should contains some `attribute` (with placeholder) from `user`, which refers to groups, where current user is a member.

See [Spring Security Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml).

Comment: This does not work. Here is my changed config.                                   <security:ldap-server id="ldapServer"
  url="${ldap.url}/o=xxxx.com" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:ldap-authentication-provider
   server-ref="ldapServer" group-search-filter="member={0}"
   group-search-base="ou=groups" user-search-base="ou=people"
   user-search-filter="uid={0}"/>

 </security:authentication-manager>

Comment: Well. You should show your LDAP tree: users and groups

Comment: Here is my directory tree...

     - xxxx.com
     + Directory Administrators
     - Groups 
    + PDRC
    - RM-CMS
      A1106738
   A8373979
   A7997979
     - People
    + A1106738
    + A8373979
    + A7997979
    + A9378437
    + A2349899
   --------

Comment: No, I need see the structure, not data. Need `ldif`